# Add data from a REGION FeatureCollection to my polygons FeatureCollection

Tags: javascript, google-earth-engine, features, feature-collection

I have generated a FeatureCollection of polygons and calculated the centroid and added it. I now want to pull in some data from FAO/GAUL/2015/level2 dataset with fields such as ADM2_CODE etc. This can be just the centroid.

How do I get data out of one FeatureCollection and add it to mine?

```
var fromList = ee.FeatureCollection("FAO/GAUL/2015/level2");

var filter = ee.Filter.inList('ADM2_NAME', ['Gwent']);
var filteredArea = fromList.filter(filter);

Map.setCenter(1.1, 51.5, 8);
Map.addLayer(filteredArea, {}, 'Regions');

var gfc2018= ee.Image('UMD/hansen/global_forest_change_2018_v1_6').clip(filteredArea);

var lossImage = gfc2018.select(['lossyear']).gte(7);
var lossBand = lossImage.and(gfc2018.select(['lossyear']).lte(20));
var zones = lossBand.updateMask(lossBand.neq(0));

// Add the loss layer in red.
Map.addLayer(lossImage.updateMask(lossBand),
            {palette: ['FF0000']}, 'Loss 2007 onwards');

var area_threshold = 300; // about 30 hectares?

// Define whole county as a region
var geom = filteredArea.geometry();

// Convert the zones of the forest loss areas to vectors.
var vectors = zones.addBands(zones).reduceToVectors({
  geometry: geom,
  crs: lossBand.projection(),
  scale: 30,
  geometryType: 'polygon',
  eightConnected: true,
  labelProperty: 'zone',
  reducer: ee.Reducer.count()
}).filterMetadata("count","greater_than", area_threshold);

// Make a display image for the vectors, add it to the map.
var display = ee.Image(0).updateMask(0).paint(vectors, '000000', 1);
Map.addLayer(display, {palette: '000000'}, 'vectors');

var SRTM = ee.Image("USGS/SRTMGL1_003"); // exampleelevation image

var slope = ee.Terrain.slope(SRTM);

// add min, max and mean elevation of each geometry
var reducers = ee.Reducer.median()
                .combine(ee.Reducer.min(), 'Elevation', true)
                .combine(ee.Reducer.max(), 'Elevation', true)
                .combine(ee.Reducer.mean(), 'Elevation', true);

vectors = SRTM.reduceRegions(vectors, reducers, 30);

// This function computes the feature's geometry area and adds it as a property.
var addCentroid = function(feature) {
  return feature.set({CentralPoint: feature.geometry().centroid(10)});
};

// Map the area getting function over the FeatureCollection.
var CPAdded = vectors.map(addCentroid);

// Get Admin Districts
var AreaName = filteredArea.aggregate_first("ADM2_CODE")

// How can I add the ADM2_CODE or any of the fields to my featurecollection? It can be just for the central point which I have calculated?

// Export the FeatureCollection to a CSV file.
Export.table.toDrive({
  collection: CPAdded,
  description: 'ForestPlus',
  fileFormat: 'CSV'
});
```